# Solving an equation in Python

Tags: python, equation-solving

i'm trying to solve an equation but I don't know the way to do this. I've got a vector x wich is actually a matrix type and I would like to solve the equation x.transpose()*v=0 where v is another vector

Can someone help me?

I thank you in advance

Comment: Sorry my question was not really precise, I already know x and i would like to know the vector v! I know that there is a lot of possible solutions but how can i get one with the python programming language?

Comment: What form is `x` in? Is it an array? A list? A `numpy` object? Something else?

Comment: Indeed. Some code, ANY code would be helpful in getting us pointed the right direction. Ideally, it'd be helpful to see your attempt at it so we know what direction you're headed. But at a minimum we need to see the code where you initialize x so we know what object types we're working with and the hand-worked answer for the simplest case you can manage so we can see what end product you're looking for. You can edit your question to add the code in so it's easy to find, there is a "code block" format button at the top so it will preserve your indentation and such as well.

Answer (score 2):

Take any vector at all and project it into the [orthogonal complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement) of `x`.

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86882M, Nov 30 2010, 10:35:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> x = numpy.matrix([1, 3.14, 2.73]).T
>>> P = x * x.T / (x.T * x) # projector onto the space spanned by x
>>> Pperp = numpy.identity(3) - P # projector onto x's orthogonal complement
>>> Pperp * x
matrix([[  0.00000000e+00],
        [  0.00000000e+00],
        [ -2.22044605e-16]])
>>> y = numpy.matrix(numpy.ones((3,1)))
>>> yperp = Pperp * y
>>> yperp
matrix([[ 0.62484642],
        [-0.17798225],
        [-0.02416928]])
>>> x.T * yperp
matrix([[ -4.16333634e-16]])
```

As written, this is quite unrestrained and gives a fairly arbitrary solution, but the same idea can be built up to find a set of basis vectors for all solutions.

Answer (score 1):

`x.T*v` is another way of writing the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) between vectors `x` and `v`, so it sounds like you want to find a vector `v` which is [orthogonal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal) to `x`.  For the general case, there are infinitely many solutions (in 3 dimensions, imagine any vector `v` in the *plane* perpendicular to x).

You have said in your comment you know there are a lot of possible solutions, and how can you get *one*, so here is one for you:

```
v = 0
```